# How can I run a script with sudo? I get ".: command not found"

Tags: sudo

I want to run a script, but the script has some `cd`s in it so I have to run it like this

```
. /scriptfile
```

This works but I also have some `sudo`s in the script as well. While everything is working but I wanted to try running the entire script with `sudo` so that I can remove all `sudo`s from the script file.
But, I couldn't run the following (with `sudo`)

```
sudo . /scriptfile
```

by trying to run I get

```
sudo: .: command not found
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: can you include more details and context? The script itself would probably be helpful.  Also if you would include the exact input alongside the complete corresponding output so that we can understand the problem

Answer (score 4):

You need to run

```
sudo ./scriptfile
```

You tried

```
sudo . /scriptfile
```

which is different due to the space after the dot. `.` or it's equivalent `source` is a shell builtin, not a command. That's why the command you tried produces the error `sudo: .: command not found`.

Note:

```
./scriptfile
```

will execute the file with the name `scriptfile` in the current directory. The file needs to be executable.

```
. /scriptfile
```

will source the file `/scriptfile` (remind that this is an absolute path here). The file doesn't need to be executable to do this, it only needs to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo su` beforehand, then you can just run `./scriptfile`